# Algebraic expression depending if variable is even or odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd like to find an algebraic expression for $f(p)$ that meets the following:

$$
f(p) = \begin{cases}
1 \, \, \text{if $p$ is even} \\
0 \, \, \text{if $p$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: $\frac {1+(-1)^{p}} 2$

Comment: looks ok for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user Kavi Rama Murthy, a possible solution is

$\frac{1+(-1)^p}{2}$.